# unable to fill listbox from another listbox and a database

Tags: c#, listbox

I am doing a windows forms app with a db connection.
I want to click on listbox1 items and do a query to a db table and fill listbox2 according to that entry.

listbox1 has teams.
listbox2 has members of those teams.

Currently this is the method I am using on the listbox1 whenever someone selects an item:

```
        string teamSelected = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        conexion = new dbconnector();

        conexion.getMembersOfTeam(ref employeesM, teamSelected);
        this.listBox2.DisplayMember = "userID";
        this.listBox2.ValueMember = "userID"; //Field in the datatable which you want to be the value of the combobox
        this.listBox2.DataSource = employeesM.Tables["users_table"];
```

however I am getting this error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The line of code which is triggering that is:

```
datasetMembers.Tables.Add(employeesM);
```

The full code of the method is:

```
public void getMembersOfTeam(ref DataSet datasetMembers, string teamDesired)
    {

        string query4 = "select * from users_table Where userTeam = '" + teamDesired + "'"; //added by fran to retrieve all the teams
        if (OpenConnection())
        {

            //retrieving all the teams using query3
            MySqlCommand cmd4 = new MySqlCommand(query4, connection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader4 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
            dataReader4.Read();

            if (dataReader4.HasRows)
            {
                //dataGridView1.Visible = true;

                DataTable employeesM = new DataTable();
                employeesM.Load(dataReader4);
                datasetMembers.Tables.Add(employeesM);

            }
            else
            {
                //dataGridView1.Visible = false;
            }


            dataReader4.Close();
            //end of retrieving teams

            CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

How can I send all those results from the query to a suitable dataset and update the listbox1?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help, I think I have share everything to make clear my question, if you need more data, let me know
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like datasetMembers is null. Have you initialized it before calling the  getMembersOfTeam method?

Comment: IT WORKED!!!, thank you so much!  
how do I mark this question as solved?

Comment: you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasetMembers is null. You have to initialized it before calling the getMembersOfTeam method.